# Change or Remove Master on View

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list-view, 2016

Created a view in SharePoint 2016.  Want the view to display on an intranet page.

The view has a master page on it.  I don't want this displayed.
(I've tried using the CSS option but can't figure out where to place it and it hasn't worked so far.)

Can I either change it to a new blank.master or can I just remove it?

I don't want the site default master changed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the same as SharePoint 2013, you can change its `master page` as the following:

- Open SharePoint Designer.
- Go to all files.
- Lists.
- Select your List.
- Select your view page
- Edit it as Advanced Mode.
- At the first line change its Master Page.

[image]

- To your required Master Page

[image]

- In my case, the default site Master was `Seattle` and I have to change it to `Oslo`.
- Browse the view it's should now be shown with the assigned master Page without changing the default site master page.

[image]

- the others view shown with default Master Page (Seattle).

[image]

Comment: When I switch to any of the supplied masters the SharePoint bars still show.  So I either need to create a blank one or pull the listview from sharepoint.

Right new I pull a listview - load it into a blank .aspx page in sharepoint then pull that page thru to the intranet.  The problem is the page contains a folder list and then files underneath.  When I click on the folder link - nothing opens.  When I right click on the folder link it will open in a new window.

Comment: Dear @jslist is this a new issue or related to the same question ? please, should you tell me specifically what you face now ?